# WildFly 10 Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

currently I'm upgrading from JBoss to Wildfly 10 (Java 8). It works fine until I got this error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: JBWEB004062: 
Unable to compile class for JSP: JBWEB004061
```

Generally speaking, the server is not able to find my class packages (imports) to resolve. These imports are not libraries. The java packages are in the WEB-INF/classes folder.
Testing different Java versions did not help (one proposed solution in the web).

Is there a different folder hierarchy in Wildfly 10 compared to the former JBoss?

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Why the package not in WEB-INF/classes folder but in WEB-INF/src?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I edit the answer. Of course, the packages are in the classes folder.

Comment: May be you can try to use the latest ecj jar (ecj-4.6.1.jar) in wildfly10

Comment: Sorry, this did not help

Comment: example of jsp that fails to compile?

Comment: I'm not allowed to share code snippets (yes, it's not that helpful). The failing jsp is the first jsp - when the application starts. This jsp includes (pure) java scriptlets which cause the error. Disregarding this bad coding style, I just want to start the server for debug-reasons.